# Is there a way to restrict an XML attribute's string length in the Relax NG Compact syntax?

Tags: xml, string, relaxng, string-length

I have an attribute I want to restrict to a maximum length of 25 characters. The XML schema is defined in Relax NG Compact syntax. Is there a way to specify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yep](http://www.relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2814737).

```
attribute myExample {
  xsd:string { maxLength = "25" }
}
```